# Click website button with VBA selenium basic

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on the web using VBA, Selenium and Chrome.

I need to authorize on website. It has worked but now fails.

If I run the website manually, input login-password and put submit, it works.
If I run VBA code the button is not clickable.

```vb
Sub Run_Test()
Dim dr As New ChromeDriver
Dim el As WebElement
Dim Login, password As String

Login = "vasilenko12": password = "1204"

dr.Get ("https://www.perevirkaznan.com/")
Sleep 1000

Set el = dr.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='navigation__enter js-modal']")
el.Click
Sleep 30

Set el = dr.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='login']")
el.SendKeys Login
Sleep 30

Set el = dr.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='password']")
el.SendKeys password
Sleep 30

Set el = dr.FindElementByXPath("//label[@class='checkbox']")
el.Click
Sleep 30

Set el = dr.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='btn btn-blue-transparent modal-submit']")
el.Click
Sleep 1000

dr.Get ("https://www.perevirkaznan.com/account/course")
Sleep 30
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it the first item that you are not able to click? Also instead of using sleep, trying using the built in wait time for selenium vba: `dr.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='navigation__enter js-modal']", 5000)` Also, remember XPATH is the slowest method, try ID, classname, and name first before trying that.

Comment: It is one button, who I can't click from code. Also when I run my code, and website loads in Chrome, I can't click this button in hand-mode
I now about the slowest speed of XPATH method, but it has been worked fast for me.

Answer (score 0):

## What is happening

Every time I tested page throwed some errors which means that button is actually being clicked:

> [image: 1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () 2. POST https://www.perevirkaznan.com/login 400]

What we have here is a **Communicability issue** where **page** is not showing an error message.

According to authors Raquel Prates, Clarisse de Souza and Simone Barbosa in their [article](https://interactions.acm.org/archive/view/jan.-feb.-2000/methods-and-tools-a-method-for-evaluating-the-communicability-of-user-), they explain that there is some "breakdown situations and user attitudes likely to occur during human-computer interaction" where under the question "Why doesn't it? (What happened?)" they describe:

> "The alternative scenario (What happened?) is when they [Users] do not get
> feedback from the system and are apparently unable to assign meaning
> to the function's outcome (halt for a moment)."

Based on that, **the page** you are attempting to login **is not showing you any error message** in user interface (Form) despite your username and password are not incorrect, and that leads you to think that your code has some problem (which is not true, your code is fine) But is showing some error in console (DevTools)

## What you cand do

According to James Scott on his [article](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-write-the-perfect-error-message-ffc132fda06a) he explains that:

> “Effective error messages inform users that a problem occurred,
> explain why it happened, and provide a solution so users can fix the
> problem. Users should either perform an action or change their
> behavior as the result of an error message.”

Based on this context you can try to explore more after the error that it's actually being shown **in console** which is a 400 error.

If we go this way we can assume that the problem is some bug at loading the page. For that, we can dodge the problem. I have tested this code several times already and found out that both errors shown in console do matter, in fact when reCaptcha API or Ads API from google shows an error or does not load to the page, Submit button does not work. This is because using ReCaptcha was a must for developers who made the page when using forms to create the login interface (yes, you are login through that object); integrating this resources to the page made it more buggy, so we need a workaround.

## Workaround

So this is my approach in the meantime the page does not solve the bug. You can wait for an element that would've been shown when you sucessfully login. For that I've used **logout button** as a reference. If your button is not shown, then try again. This is what the code does. Usually it fails one time and works in the second one.

```
Sub stackoverflow_test2()
    Dim dr As New ChromeDriver
    Dim el As webElement
    Dim Login, password As String

    Login = "vasilenko12": password = "1204"
    
try:
    dr.Get ("https://www.perevirkaznan.com/")
    Sleep 1000

    Set el = dr.FindElementByCss("a.navigation__enter.js-modal")
    el.Click
    Sleep 30

    Set el = dr.FindElementByCss("input[name=login]")
    el.SendKeys Login
    Sleep 30
    
    Set el = dr.FindElementByCss("input[type=password]")
    el.SendKeys password
    Sleep 30

    Set el = dr.FindElementByCss("label[class=checkbox]")
    el.Click
    Sleep 30

    Set el = dr.FindElementByCss("button[type=submit]")
    el.Click
    Sleep 1000
    
    Success = CBool(dr.FindElementsByCss("a.navigation__logout").Count > 0)
    If Not Success Then GoTo try:


    dr.Get ("https://www.perevirkaznan.com/account/course")
    Sleep 30


End Sub
```